# Sublime Text run python works on mac but not on windows 8

Tags: python, sublimetext

On my mac in sublime text:

```
# farenhiet to celcius
def farenheit2celcious (farenheit):
celcius = (5 / 9) * (farenheit - 32)
return celcius

#test
c1 = farenheit2celcious(32)
print c1
```

gives 0 in console

in windows, in sublime text, I get

print c1
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Any ideas?  Line endings?  File is same file accessed by different computers from dropbox.  Both environments have sublime text 2, probably with different packages installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have python 3 installed on windows, it will be a problem. I am assuming python on MAC is python2.x and the one on windows is 3.x

In python 3, print is a function, so it should be print(c1)

You can check python version by:

1. Just type python on console on Mac, you will see the version
2. Open IDLE on windows and see what is the version printed

Comment: Yes that is it. I changed to print (c1) to test and boom it worked on my windows box.  So I will change environments to 2x on windows for consistency for now.  Thanks!